# How to always use external monitor

Tags: display, monitor, external-monitor

When I plugin my external monitor through HDMI, I can switch to "External Only" by pressing `win+P`. But when I logout & login the system, it reverts back to using both laptop & external monitor.

Can I save my settings so I can always ONLY use the external monitor (if it is available) when I login?

Comment: what is your Operating System and DE if you installed other than Default?

Comment: You could perhaps work around the issue by setting the laptop lid-close to NOT suspend/shutdown. Then just open-lid, power on laptop and close-lid and it should output to monitor only. Works for me anyway! Search for the `tweaks` tool in the Ubuntu software center. `Suspend when laptop lid is closed` is a toggle option on the first screen.